# Issues with Makefile on Mac OS X : no target found

Tags: macos, makefile

I am working on a makefile on OS X and I'm having issues. I've made everything as I am supposed to (I think) but only part of it is working. When I try :

```
make file1
```

or:

```
make file2
```

everything seems fine but when I try :

```
make all
```

or:

```
make clean
```

I get the typical :

```
*** No rule to make target
```

Here's the code, I hope you can spot the issue(s) :

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
FILES=file1 file2

all: $(FILES)

file1: file1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) file1.c -o file1

file2: file2.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) file2.c -o file2

clean: 
    $(RM) $(FILES)
```

Cheers !

Comment: There's no obvious reason why the syntax shown would cause that problem, so I suspect that `make file1` is working without any makefile and coming up with a default rule to do the compilation (and probably doesn't use the `-Wall` option when compiling).  What's the name of the makefile you created?

Comment: the makefile is named makefile, and you are indeed right : `-Wall` isn't used (I just noticed)

Comment: That's curious.  Take a close look at the name: `ls m* | od -c`.  See if the letters are what you expect, and there's no trailing space at the end of the name or anything untoward like that.  But the 'no `-Wall`' observation practically confirms that the trouble is with the name of the `makefile`, though it isn't yet obvious why it is not working.  You could try `make -f makefile all` and see whether that makes any difference.

Comment: My Terminal doesn't seem to be on my side for that, but I tried remaking a `makefile` from scratch containing exactly the same information and it runs smoothly. You were definitely right about the name issue @JonathanLeffler, and thanks for all useful tips (in case it happens again, but not a name issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer, mainly so the question can be closed.*</sup>

There's no obvious reason why the syntax shown would cause that problem, so I suspect that `make file1` is working without any makefile and coming up with a default rule to do the compilation (and probably doesn't use the `-Wall` option when compiling).

What's the name of the makefile you created?

> The makefile is named `makefile`, and you are indeed right: `-Wall` isn't used (I just noticed).

That's curious. Take a close look at the name: `ls m* | od -c`. See if the letters are what you expect, and there's no trailing space at the end of the name or anything untoward like that.

But the 'no `-Wall`' observation practically confirms that the trouble is with the name of the `makefile`, though it isn't yet obvious why it is not working. You could try `make -f makefile all` and see whether that makes any difference.  If the name is wrong, you should get told that it can't open the `makefile`.

> I tried remaking a `makefile` from scratch containing exactly the same information and it runs smoothly. You were definitely right about the name issue.

That sort of problem is bizarre and confusing — it was sensible to get help.